# Network Analysis - Manipulating data - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I'm using the `networkD3` package and I'm trying to do some network analysis

Let's say I have this data:

```
src <- c("Dizzy Gillespie","Louis Armstrong","Max Roach","Charlie Parker","Charlie Parker")
target <- c("Chet Baker","Chet Baker","Peter Erskine","John Coltrane","Wayne Shorter")
group <- c("Trumpet","Trumpet","Drums","Saxophone","Saxophone")

networkData <- data.frame(src, target,group)
```

I've read this documentation https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/ but they won't tell how they manipulated the data on `MisLinks` and `MisNodes` to create the other columns... how could I manipulate my data frame so it could work on the `forceNetwork()` function like the one on Les miserables data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `simpleNetwork` directly like this: `simpleNetwork(networkData)`

If you want to use `forceNetwork`, the help page says that the `Nodes` data frame is "a data frame containing the node id and properties of the nodes. If no ID is specified then the nodes must be in the same order as the Source variable column in the Links data frame. Currently only a grouping variable is allowed.", so it should look something like this...

```
#             names     group
# 1 Dizzy Gillespie   Trumpet
# 2 Louis Armstrong   Trumpet
# 3       Max Roach     Drums
# 4  Charlie Parker Saxophone
# 5      Chet Baker   Trumpet
# 6   Peter Erskine     Drums
# 7   John Coltrane Saxophone
# 8   Wayne Shorter Saxophone
```

which you could create from your `networkData` data frame like this...

```
col_names <- c("name", "group")
nodes <- rbind(setNames(networkData[c(1, 3)], col_names), 
               setNames(networkData[c(2, 3)], col_names))
nodes <- unique(nodes)
```

The help page says that the `Links` data frame is "a data frame object with the links between the nodes. It should include the Source and Target for each link. These should be numbered starting from 0. An optional Value variable can be included to specify how close the nodes are to one another.", so it should look something like this...

```
#   src target
# 1   0      4
# 2   1      4
# 3   2      5
# 4   3      6
# 5   3      7
```

which you could then create using your `networkData` data frame and the `nodes` data frame created above like this...

```
networkData$src <- match(networkData$src, nodes$name) - 1
networkData$target <- match(networkData$target, nodes$name) - 1
networkData$group <- NULL
```

then you pass them to `forceNetwork` and tell it the names of the columns in your data frames like this...

```
forceNetwork(Links = networkData, Nodes = nodes, Source = "src", 
             Target = "target", NodeID = "name", Group = "group")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to put some "weight" on the circles? For example, if someone has more links the circle would be bigger...

Comment: check out the help file... all of this info is in there. `nodes$node_size <- 1:nrow(nodes) * 10; forceNetwork(Links = networkData, Nodes = nodes, Source = "src", Target = "target", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", Nodesize = "node_size")`

Comment: FYI... you can read the help file by typing this in the R console `?forceNetwork`