# Network Analysis - networkD3 - How to put Weight

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I've read the documentation in https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/ and managed to do the `forceNetwork()` graph.

But how could i set "weight" on the circles?

For example, if someone has more links, it's circle would be bigger.

The graph i managed to plot kept all the circles with the same size.

Comment: what code/data did you use to make your plot?

Comment: `Nodesize = weight` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804146/network-analysis-manipulating-data-shiny/50806111#50806111
here's the data

Comment: @G5W is it? I don't know... i didn't see any of this examples with the circles bigger according to the weight of it

Comment: The documentation mentions this parameter.  Did you  try to add this to your `forceNetwork` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Nodesize` parameter of the `forceNetwork` function to refer to the name of the column in your `Nodes` data frame that contains numeric values which will be used to determine the size of each node. For example...

`forceNetwork(Links = networkData, Nodes = nodes, Source = "src", Target = "target", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", Nodesize = "node_size")`

The help file says "Nodesize: character string specifying the a column in the Nodes data frame with some value to vary the node radius's with. See also radiusCalculation."